# Bootstrap 5 Modal with select2 auto close

Tags: laravel, select, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5, jquery-select2

I have problem with my Bootstrap 5 modal select2. When I open the modal and I scroll down the form and I click select which is using select2, the modal auto closes. I will share the code, maybe you all know about the problem, by the way I used cork admin template in my project.

```
<div class="modal fade text-left" id="tambahBuku" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="tambahBuku" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content" id="modal-reload">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Tambah Buku</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="/dashboard/buku" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="judulBuku">Judul Buku</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="judulBuku" id="judulBuku"
                            placeholder="Judul Buku">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="kategoriBukuTambah">Kategori</label>
                        <select style="margin-bottom: 0%" name="kategori" class="form-control select2"
                            id="kategoriBukuTambah">
                            @foreach ($kategoriBuku as $kategori)
                            <option value="{{$kategori->id}}">{{$kategori->judul_kategori}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="penerbitBukuTambah">Penerbit</label>
                        <select class="form-control select2" name="penerbit" id="penerbitBukuTambah">
                            @foreach ($penerbitBuku as $penerbit)
                            <option value="{{$penerbit->id}}">{{$penerbit->nama_penerbit}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="deskripsi">Deskripsi</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="deskripsi" id="deskripsi" cols="30" rows="5"
                            placeholder="Deskripsi"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="jumlahSalinan">Jumlah Salinan</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="jumlahSalinan" name="jumlahSalinan"
                            placeholder="Jumlah Salinan">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="hargaBuku">Harga Buku</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="hargaBuku" name="hargaBuku"
                            placeholder="Harga Buku">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="image">Pilih Gambar</label>
                        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image" name="gambar" onchange="previewImage();">
                    </div>
                    <img id="image-preview" src="#" alt="Image preview..."
                        style="display: none; max-width: 200px; max-height: 200px;">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button id="modal-blockui" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$('#kategoriBukuTambah').select2({
            dropdownParent: $('#tambahBuku')
            
        });
        $('#penerbitBukuTambah').select2({
            dropdownParent: $('#tambahBuku')
            
        });
```

```
<script>
    // Lakukan ini sebelum Anda menginisialisasi salah satu modal Anda
    $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {};
</script>
```

Thank you

I hope when I choose select2 in any condition it not closed